# Spring Security REST API roles based on URL parameters

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I have a REST API written in Spring Boot with Spring Security and OAuth2. The resources are secured this way:

```java
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/security/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
}
```

I'd like to introduce a new part of the API where the permissions are fine grained, based on projects. Let's consider a simple endpoint that prints the project configuration.

```
GET /api/v1/project/{projectId}/config
```

How would I configure the resource server to only allow access for users who have the role `ROLE_PROJECT_{projectId}_ADMIN` without having to manually specify all projects?

Also if this mechanism has a specific name, please let me know in comments to I can change the question title.

Comment: If you're using Spring MVC, putting `@PreAuthorize` annotations on controller methods is typically the best way to handle fine-grained permissions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use path values in authorization expressions.

According to [Path Variables in Web Security Expressions](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.2.x/reference/html/el-access.html#el-access-web-path-variables) you should write your custom authorization logic.

```
public class WebSecurity {
  public boolean checkUserHasAccessToProjectId(Authentication authentication, int projectId) {
    // here you can check if the user has the correct role
    // or implement more complex and custom authorization logic if necessary 
  }
}
```

Then in your Java security configuration you can refer to this method and pass it the value of the relevant path fragment.

```
http.authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/api/v1/project/{projectId}/config")
  .access("@webSecurity.checkUserHasAccessToProjectId(authentication,#projectId)")
  ...
```